# How to translate select keys efficiently and where to get the translated resources?

Tags: php, html, laravel, internationalization, translation

I've got the following situation

```
{!! Form::select('country', [
    "NL" => "Netherlands",
    "US" => "United States",
    "GB" => "United Kingdom"
], $user->country, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

*note that the select in my application is much bigger in my application about 400+ options*

I store the key (the value attribute of the option tag) in a `country` field in my database associated with the user that's being edited.
For example I live in the Netherlands so my `country` would be NL, when I read the value from the database and show in my template it only echo's NL

```
{!! $user->country !!}
// NL
```

I want it to echo the correct translation according to the language that's chosen so:

- In dutch it will be Nederland
- In english it will be The Netherlands
- In german it will be Holländisch
- In french it will be Néerlandais
- And so on...

I'm also wondering where to get the translation(s) resources? I've created a Dutch country list according to ISO 3166 https://gist.github.com/0x1ad2/2e1c86dda7d3561fa68d and a Dutch spoken languages list according to ISO 639 https://gist.github.com/0x1ad2/cf0c130b88c196133171 myself but there must be a easier way (I hope).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into the principle of `internationalization and localisation`, referred to as `i18n` in development.

Since you talk about a few hundred options I'd take a look at [gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/), it has [native integration](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php) with php.

Comment: I looked into localisation for Laravel and noticed it's quite easy, but to get the translations would cost a lot of effort I think (I'm not using gettext). Do you know a website to get arrays of translations (the obvious ones I could find like country but what about nationality)?

Comment: To be honest, that almost sounds like you want to have a connection with a dictionary :-) . Say you want to display the name of a country in the language that is currently chosen by a user, and you have 100 languages and 200 countries, then you are looking at (in theory) 20.000 possible translations. I don't know if such arrays of translations exist really (other than a dictionary, and then you'll need 100 of those as well...)

Comment: Sounds like a good idea for a PHP package ;) maybe we going to hire some translators for it...think that's the fastest way.

Comment: 100 translators? How big is your wallet? :-D

Comment: Does this help maybe? http://www.opengeocode.org/download.php , there are a number of country name translations in this file: http://www.opengeocode.org/download/countrynames.txt , but that's only limited

Comment: Haha we aren't going to hire 100 translators, of course we will start with a couple of languages/countries. And thanks for the url, I mostly fetch my data from Wikipedia and transform it to a PHP array using Excel and Sublime text :D

Comment: I also did find this pearl: List of all countries with names and ISO 3166-1 codes in all languages and data formats. - https://github.com/umpirsky/country-list